# Logback Audit Issue

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, slf4j, logback

I created the logback audit war with the bellow jars successfully.

slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
logback-core-1.0.6.jar
audit-server-0.6.jar
audit-common-0.6.jar
audit-client-0.6.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar

But recently the 1.0.13  version of logback-core introduced. So we uesd that. But we got the bellow error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Pattern
```

Then we tried with the logback-core version 1.0.12 but it gave the bellow error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch.qos.logback.core.status.StatusChecker
```

Then we tried with the logback-core version 1.0.11 and it worked fine.

Can anybody please tell me what is the stable version of the bellow jars for logback audit perpose?

slf4j-api.jar
logback-core.jar
audit-server.jar
audit-common.jar
audit-client.jar
slf4j-log4j12.jar
log4j.jar

Comment: not sure if you're still having issues with this but I opened a ticket for this issue http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LBAUDIT-5 and I documented what I had to do to get around it in the ticket.  I think logback-audit is a dead project but I am hoping they will work on it and get it up to date.

Answer (score 2):

The pom file states that logback-audit 0.6 requires logback-core 1.0.9

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cch.qos.logback%7Caudit-parent%7C0.6%7Cpom

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same logback version for logback-core, logback-classic.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```